# Navigation not working in IE8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, drop-down-menu, navigation, onclick

I have a full width 3 level navigation, please see:

http://acemenu.zzcreative.com/test/logged-in.php

I am checking the menu across all browsers, in IE8 the menu does not appear when clicking the 'Menu' link.

Also I am told it does not work to well in FF on a PC?

Any ideas?

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link 
to the site that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value
to future visitors once the problem is solved. Posting a 
[Short, Self Contained, Correct Example (SSCCE)](http://www.sscce.org/) 
that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, 
see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to
it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Comment: thanks for the comment, I am sorry I was not aware of this. OK, I think the issue maybe my .js file: its too long to post, i may close this question and open a new one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The menu displays in IE when you remove the z-index: 999 from the div with id sticky-header-logged-in

Comment: This seems to have fixed the issue in IE8. Had to add a few Z-index's to other DIVs, seems fine now. Thank you for your help.